# ASP .NET Web API SaveChangesAsync with Foreign Key Data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have Customer and Address classes, something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int ShippingAddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ShippingAddressId")]
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

When I call a Web API to update the Customer, I pass an edited Customer object to this method. For example, I edit 2 properties: Customer.CustomerName and Customer.ShippingAddress.City

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await new AuthHelper().AcquireTokenSilentAsync();
if (ar.Token == null) return false;
using (var json = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity), UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.ApiUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ar.Token);
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync("api/" + type.ToString() + "/" + id, json))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await InsertOrReplaceResponse(type, response);
    }
}
```

Here is the Web API:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutCustomer([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Customer customer)
{
    _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent);
}
```

However, only Customer.CustomerName gets updated. The foreign key data (Customer.ShippingAddress.City) isn't updated in the Address table.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I would expect the child `Address` entity to be update as well because you use foreign key association which also should be the default for one-to-one mappings (see [here](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/) for more details). However, it seems that something is not setup right and you get independent association behavior where you have to manage child entity state yourself. Should be a simple fix in your case:

```
_context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.Entry(customer.ShippingAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: Thanks. I swear I tried that before and it didn't work, but now it does. I must have had something else wrong in my code at the time. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious of one thing.. What if I try to update a Customer and Address where the Customer already exists and the Address does not exist. Will it be smart enough to update the Customer and insert the new Address?

Comment: @Primico you will have to set the `State` of the `ShippingAddress` entity to `EntityState.Added`. EF will throw an exception if it is `Modified` for a new address. I would recommend to handle address id generation in you API. This way if address came with an id, the API will update it. If it came without id, the API will try to create a new address.

Comment: That makes sense. I can do something like this:                         _context.Entry<Address>(customer.ShippingAddress).State = customer.ShippingAddress.Id > 0 ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
However, would EF know to update Customer.ShippingAddressId with the ID of the newly created Address?

Comment: Nevermind the last question. I just tested and it works. Thanks so much!